# object creation in stack

Tags: c#, .net, memory-management, object

Can I create an object of my class in stack regarding .net and C#?
For example:

```
class abc { int i=1; } 
abc a1=new abc();
```

Now, here the object is created in heap. So, is there any way to create the object in stack memory of ram if the size of object is not big?

Comment: you mean your own stack? or in objets stack?

Comment: Your question is unclear (I can't tell what you're looking for). You question might be closed unless you can clarify what you're looking for

Comment: class abc
{
   int i=1;
}

abc a1=new abc();

now, here the object is created in heap.
so, is there any way to create the object in stack memory of ram as the size of object is not big?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.NET reference types always live on the GC heap. It's not possible to have them elsewhere. Even C++/CLI that supports things like

```
System::Random rnd;
rnd.Next();
```

that looks like stack variables, actually creates the `Random` class, on the GC heap (and calls its `Dispose` method at the end of the block if it implements `IDisposable`.)

That said, as Eric Lippert says, [the stack is an implementation detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx) and you should primarily care about reference or value semantics of the types you create.

Answer (score 2):

Use of the stack for objects (class instances) is not available. However, use of `struct` instead of `class`, creates a value-type that will be created on the stack.  There's [lots of things to consider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229017%28VS.80%29.aspx) about this.  The book *Framework Design Guidelines* doesn't make a concrete suggestion, but indicates it's probably best to benchmark the differences and determine if it's really worth implementing a value-type.

---

Side Note: Enabling objects to use the stack is under discussion. This is one of the several issues on github related to objects on the stack:
https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/6653

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you need an object on the stack instead of the heap. The main reason for that (at least the main reason I know) is RAII. The compiler in c++ guarantees that each object created on the stack is destroyed when it leaves scope.

In C# you archive the same thing with the using-statement: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx

Comment: One might think that the `using` statement uses the stack, but it doesn't. The `using` statement allows freeing resources used by object, but not the object itself. (See IDisposable.)

Answer (score -1):

As Mehrdad says, reference type instances (objects) are stored on the heap, along with things like static variables.  Local variables and the like are stored on the stack.

Answer (score -1):

To understand the interest of the cpu stack. You have to learn how the cpu work (assembler language). Allocating a space on the stack is a quasi instantaneous and very precise allocation/free memory block, because it's just a single register value to change. While allocating on heap require algorithmic research, eventualy allocating space on the disk, ect. If you have little structure like Point, PointF it's very important to have access to the stack memory instead of reserving large space pages on heap for a few temporary micro structures.